# How does the inner product (-,-) with norm ||.|| relate to bilinear and linear forms in the FEM?

Tags: normed-spaces, bilinear-form, finite-element-method

I am attempting to prove the Lax-Milgram lemma for the weak formulation of the finite element method. However I first need to prove continuity of the bilinear and linear forms ($a(u,v)$ and $l(v)$), plus coercivity of the bilinear form. I am struggling to understand how they connect to the norm. I know the $u$ and $v$ lie in the hilbert space $H^1(\Omega)$ with the $L^2$ norm.

I have that 
$a(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}\bigtriangledown u\cdot\bigtriangledown v$

so does that make the norm associated with it
$||\bigtriangledown u\cdot\bigtriangledown v||$?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use Lax-Milgram lemma, you must show continuity of the bilinear form $a$ in the space which is *relevant* to the posed problem. Suppose that you are solving
$$- \Delta u = f$$
in domain $\Omega$ with the boundary condition $u|_{\partial \Omega}=0$. Then the weak formulation reads: find $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that
$$(\nabla u, \nabla v) = (f,v)$$
holds for every $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$. Now $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space with the norm
$$\|w\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}:=\|\nabla w\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$$
and, therefore, the continuity follows immediately from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$(\nabla u, \nabla v) \leq \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|\nabla v\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.$$
Moreover, coercivity is obvious:
$$(\nabla u, \nabla u) = \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2.$$

**Another example.** Suppose that you are solving a pure Neumann problem:
$$- \Delta u = f$$
in domain $\Omega$ with the boundary condition $(\nabla u \cdot n)|_{\partial \Omega}=0$. Then the weak formulation is: find $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that
$$(\nabla u, \nabla v) = (f,v)$$
holds for every $v \in H^1(\Omega)$. Now the respective norm is
$$\|w\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 := \|\nabla w\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 +\|w\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2$$
Continuity can be proven somewhat similarly as before but now you cannot show the coercivity:
$$(\nabla u, \nabla u) = \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \geq~???$$
Thus, the solution to this problem is not unique. In order to make the solution unique, you can for example include the constraint
$$\int_\Omega u \,\mathrm{d}x = 0.$$
With this constraint you can use the Poincaré-Friedrich's inequality to get
$$(\nabla u, \nabla u) = \frac 12 \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2+\frac 12 \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \geq \frac 12 \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \frac{1}{2C}\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \geq \frac{1}{2 \max(1,C)} \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2. $$

**In conclusion,** the correct norm depends on the space where the weak problem is posed in. You cannot deduce the correct norm by just looking at the bilinear form; you also have to know the boundary conditions.

Comment: square missing after "Moreover, coercivity is obvious"